# Selecting rows for a training data set when target is not uniformly distributed

Tags: r, decision-tree

Having the following code to create a data set for training a decision tree:

```
set.seed(2)
train_sample <- sample(nrow(X), nrow(X) * 0.7)
X_test <- X[-train_sample,]
```

This will create a training sample containing 70% of the data and a test sample containing the other 30%.

The problem I am having is that this does not take into consideration that some of the values in the target column are rarer than others. For example, the target column could contain values ranging from 4 to 8. However, 90% of them is ranging from 5 to 7. Meaning only 10% of the entire (target) data is a 4 or 8.

How should I best approach this, should I take this into consideration when building a training set or should I ignore it? And how can I take this into consideration building a training set if I should? Are there any easy methods to apply?

Comment: @zx8754 what was it called I should search for: stratified sampling?

Comment: Yes, stratified sampling.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `createDataPartition` in `caret` and provide the label in the function, for example:

```
library(caret)
X = iris[c(1:20,51:150),]
X$Species = factor(X$Species=="setosa")
table(X$Species)

FALSE  TRUE 
  100    20 
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(X$Species, p = .7, 
                                  list = FALSE, 
                                  times = 1)

table(X[trainIndex,]$Species)
FALSE  TRUE 
   70    14
```

Else you can also do it with tapply maybe:

```
trainIndex = unlist(tapply(1:nrow(X),
X$Species,function(i){
sample(i,round(length(i)*0.7))
}))

table(X[trainIndex,]$Species)

FALSE  TRUE 
   70    14
```

In the above code, you split 1:nrow(X) according to labels and sample within each group.